# Why doesn't the Application dohicky install the latest software version?

Tags: applications

So doing a bit of playing around with Elementary.  I got it installed on a big USB SSD drive I have and it's working well.

Except, installing non-curated software from the Applications tools results in very old versions of the software being installed.

Installing GIMP via the App tool installed v2.8 whereas the latest is 2.10.20
Installing Digikam installed v 5.6 where the lastest is v7.0

Getting the latest of these two installed was a bit of a flail with a goodly amount of digging and command line activity beyond a simple apt-get install. GMP was not too bad, Digikam was a struggle.

Why?

Answer (score 0):

If you go to flathub you can install the Gimp flatpack from there.  From there forward flatpacks will show up in the App Center.DigiKam is there as well.

By default, App Center seems to have the version in the ubuntu repositories.  I don't now if any repository carries the latest Gimp.

edit:  Clarity